# WLST : Which mBean to access deployments>monitoring>workload>Work Managers

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c, wlst

I am working on rolling weblogic manager servers start up scripts using python and wlst.

Once server is started and comes in running mode I have to check if manage server Completed Requests > 0. If its more than 0 then proceed to next manager server and bring it down.

So I am looking to access the Completed Requests count using wlst but not sure which mBean to use which can provide me the details.

I can see the detail in weblogic console from below path

domain>Deployments>Monitoring>Work Load>Work Manager (default)

How to find the exact mBean to access the above details.

Comment: You can easily find your mbean with the console. The help gives the corresponding mbean to each information displayed in the console.

Comment: @EmmanuelCollin The help gives the path *within* the mbean to get individual properties, but does not give the path to the mbean itself - so far as I can see.

Comment: Your question was how to find the mbean.
Anyway, the way i use to find the path to the mbean is to read the [mbean reference documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12212/wls/WLMBR/core/index.html) provided by Oracle. Once you have your mbean name its easy to find it in the mbean reference. From there, you will find access points to the bean.